# Ajax response redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, jsonresponse

I have the problem in that I do ajax request, my django view handles view and return JsonResponse with content that will be replace old content. Unfortunately, response doesn't replace old content - I get redirect on the content, page looks like:

```
{"content": "<h3>\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e</h3>\n<div>\n    <a href=\"/\">\u0412\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0443\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f \u043d\u0430 \u0433\u043b\u0430\u0432\u043d\u0443\u044e \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0443</a>\n</div>", "success": true}
```

js:

```
$( '#main' ).on( 'click', '#submit', function() {
    $form = $( '#form' );
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: {
            form: $form.serialize()
        }
    }).done( function( response ) {
        console.log('ok');
        $( '#old' ).remove();
        $( '#contact' ).append(response.content);
    })
});
```

view:

```
     ...
                content = render_to_string('mock.html')
                return JsonResponse({
                    'success': True,
                    'content': content
                })
...
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: content or context??

Comment: I am sorry - content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to do something like this:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $form = $('#form');
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: {
            form: $form.serialize()
        }
    }).done( function( response ) {
        console.log('ok');
        $( '#old' ).remove();
        $( '#contact' ).append(response.content);
    })
});
```

You need to prevent the form submission.

Another way to do this is maybe by using  [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Next thing you should do is to add CSRFToken to your Ajax header, more on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Comment: I tried to use preventDefault() method, but then I get 403 Forbidden response from server - why I have no idea too(

Comment: I have no experiences with django but maybe this would help? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax and keep the prevent default line in the code or return false, you'll definitely need it.

Comment: No problem, I have updated the answer to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are sending the csrfmiddlewaretoken with your ajax request if it's a post. Otherwise you will get a 403 and possibly a redirect.

A quick way to test for this is to add the `@csrf_exempt` decorator to your view.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this:

```
$( '#contact' ).html(response.content);
```

as you want to replace it?

Comment: Yes, but problem it is not in it - .done() method does not work, because, I think, response redirects to {"content": "<h3>\u04... and .done() method does not run. But why I get the redirect instead .done() run I have no idea